# How to reference class of another module in spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I wanna seperate 2 applications in 1 project.
I'm using intelli J and Spring-boot

So I did it. There are A module(aApplication.java) and B module(bApplication.java)
and also there are 2 build.gradle files.
but I can't reference class(like Entity) from another module.

if I add dependencies B module(like implementation project(':module-B')),
It's work. but there is a problem.(#A)

It is.. subordination(?)

A, B's dependencies of build.gradle are diffrent.
but if do way #A, there are B's dependencies also in A's dependencies.

[image]

add dependencies
`implementation project(':module-B')`

I expecting two build.gradle's content.
(gradle content without interfering with each other)

becuase I will use security in B, and I don't want to use in A

[image]

Comment: What is the reason behind both projects should (must) have the same dependencies? If this is a requirement put the common class into a 3rd module and reference that in both modules.

Comment: Don't post code as images as those are unreadable, please post them as code with proper code tags for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

finally.

I seperated 3 modules.
and A, B modules reference another C module.

and I used @EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {.class, .class}) on Application.

Now, there are Entities in center module,
and I can reference them.

@AndrasCsanyi thx.

Comment: Your welcome! Anytime! :)